# Is there an equivalent of %*, or Environment.CommandLine in C?

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments

In other words, is there a way to capture the entire command line (or even the arguments part of the command line) in a single string, including all delimiters?

I'm explicitly NOT looking for solutions that involve concatenating the elements of argv.
Such solutions assume something about the delimiters or the formatting of the arguments.

For example, let's take the below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        puts(argv[i]);
}
```

If I run it like so:

```
 Test.exe 1 2
```

I get the output:

```
 Test.exe
 1
 2
```

This is not a problem, but when I run it like this:

```
Test.exe "1" "2"
```

And I get the exact same output, that's a problem.Basically, I'm trying to get the verbatim string that was issued as the command line.

Comment: Why do you have C# listed as a tag?

Comment: Environment.CommandLine is a reference to C#.

Comment: If you are using Windows use `GetCommandLine`.  This is not portable.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in method in C to retrieve the command line (or the arguments) as a single string with all quotes intact, at least not defined by the language standard.  Part of the problem is the definition of the `argv` array, and part of it is what your shell does *prior* to passing arguments to the program (such as removing quotes):

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
> ...
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
> `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, **which are given
> implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup**. The
> intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
> from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
> supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
> shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.

Emphasis mine.

There *may* be platform-specific extensions that will do what you want, but I don't personally know of any.

Answer (score 0):

`int main (int argc, char** argv)`

argc is the arguments count, argv are parameterers. They are space delimited, i believe.

If you want to merge them in one string it could be done like: (forgive me, if it's poor written).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
// --------
std::stringstream S;
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    S << argv[i];

std::string Str = S.str();
```

You might also wanna add spaces between them when merging, however, i don't think it would be much use, except for debugging purposes. Using them as they are, or putting into `vector<string>` is usually the most convenient way.

Oh, didn't realize (I always make this mistake) that it should be pure C. In that case just leave them as they are. I won't delete the above code in case anyone is gonna use it in C++.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the Environment property

```
Environment.CommandLine
```

Comment: my mistake, pls ignore this. I didn't realize you asked for C.

Answer (score 0):

Unix -- and here C shows its unix origin -- has a notion of arguments, not of command line.  Command line is parsed by the shell which splits them in arguments and a program see only the arguments.

On systems which have a notion of command line, one could pass the command line as the first argument and let the program parse them. Most C implementations don't do that -- at least by default -- they do their own argument splitting from the command line.

Depending on your context you may:

- accept that the C way is the Unix way and don't try to force something else on it;
- rebuild a command line (but you'll have to pay attention to quoting);
- use a system dependant way to get access to the unparsed command line if there is one.

The first is probably the best if you want portability, the last the best if you have to respect conventions different than what your implementation provide for argument splitting.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ don't really even the *notion* of a command line. The program just gets its arguments in the `argv` parameter of `main`. How that's done is up to the implementation.

On Windows, you can call [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx). Your program actually already calls that before `main` starts because that's what Windows programs do as part of the task of populating the `argv` array in the first place.

On Unix and Linux, the command line is parsed and broken up before your program even starts running. Command-line arguments are passed to the [`exec` family of functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).

If you need a cross-platform and portable way of reading verbatim commands, I suggest you read them from a file, not the command line. The command line is subject to massaging from the command interpreter (such as bash or cmd.exe).